# DataTables filter alias

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables

I'm using `DataTables` plugin and I would want to be able to set an alias for some cells for easy searching.

For example, I would like to be able to find "Mr. John" if I search for "Mister John".

I think I saw somewhere in the documentation about this, but I can't find it again at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTables` [Orthogonal Data](http://datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data) feature is what you are looking for. Your example might look like this:

```
<tr>
    <td data-search="Mister John">Mr. John</td>
</tr>
```

Using html5 data attributes, you can specify additional data which `DataTables` will process when searching. No further configuration is needed.

Comment: You saved my life! Thank you very much. Also, for other developers in a hurry, in order for it to work correctly, __"all cells in a column must have the same attribute available"__ and also, __not__ empty ( e.g. _data-search=""_ )